# Flutter firestore message notifications

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, notifications, messaging

I have implemented a chat app using cloud firestore.

#### The flow is like this:

1. There is a chats collection and it has both users ids saved. and chats collection has internal messages collection, where all the messages are saved.
2. both users can messages each other instantly.
3. Also any user can initiate chat with any other user.

#### What I want to know?

I want to send notification on the receiver mobile when a new message is sent. If anyone can understand the problem. Help will be appreciated <3.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this](https://medium.com/@duytq94/flutter-chat-app-extended-push-notification-messages-a26c669f4675) article that you might find useful, it is very detailed an even includes the [code](https://github.com/duytq94/firebase-function-chat-demo), basically the trick is to use **Cloud Firebase Functions** to listen any changes on the collection, in your specific use case, try to listen the `onCreate` trigger, that will be fired each time a user creates a new message (document) on the collection, more information on the Database Triggers can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)

Then you only have to trigger the `sendToDevice` [method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendtodevice) from within the `onCreate` listener to push the message into the device.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase cloud functions can be used to create and trigger functions according to your own business logic. I assume that you have configured and connected your flutter application with the firebase if not the below steps will guide you through that also.

1. [This link here will guide you on how to start with cloud functions basically what all you need to do to set up the environment.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)
2. [This link is a complete example which demonstrates on how to push notifications to a particular user device using the device token whenever a new document is added to a collection.](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2020/01/14/firebase-push-notifications-in-flutter/)
3. [This is a youtube video for the above links.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBq8tNhX_dM&t=1481s)

Please go through the links and help yourself.